# How to build a custom regex that matches dashes/alphanumeric characters and '.' dot characters that are not consecutive?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to build a regex that doesn't match the words with this requirements:

1. at least 3 characters
2. maximum 32 characters
3. only `a-z0-9_-`.
4. dots: `.` ok, `..` nope

this is what i did:

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z\-\_\.]{3,32}/
```

the problem is that i can insert more than one `.` and i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
/(?:[\w-]|\.(?!\.)){3,32}/
```

Explanation:

- `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group
- `[\w-]` - Character set to match `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`
- `|` - Alternation, or..
- `\.(?!\.)` - Negative lookahead to match a `.` character literally if it isn't followed by another `.` character.
- `)` - Close the non-capturing group
- `{3,32}` - Match the group 3 to 32 times

You may also want to add anchors if you want to match the entire string against the expression:

```
/^(?:[\w-]|\.(?!\.)){3,32}$/
```

Comment: nice! OP needs the hyphen too instead of just \w, but this seems like the direction he needed.

Comment: @GiovanniFar I updated the answer; try again. I forgot to escape the `.`, so it was matching any characters. I also added dashes, it should work now: `/^(?:[\w-]|\.(?!\.)){3,32}$/` - https://regex101.com/r/bM2eJ4/1